# "ls -la | sort +0nr -2 +2d" , what does sort do here?

Tags: unix, sorting

I hae seen this somewhere written:
ls -la | sort +0nr -2 +2d

What is sort doing here? What are these arguments.

Comment: does `man sort` help?

Comment: no, I tried man page but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an obsolete command line usage, which is still supported but not documented in the man page anymore. You can check `info coreutils 'sort invocation'` as proposed in the `see also` section of the man page.

```
ls -la | sort +0nr -2 +2d
```

is equivalent to

```
ls -la | sort -k1nr,2 -k3d
```

which on my Ubuntu outputs the same as

```
ls -la | sort -k3d
```

Comment: On Ubuntu there is an `info` command which gives information additional to what `man` displays, and this command explains the older syntax. Run `info sort` and use `/` to search for `older systems`.

Comment: @AFH actually the manpage has a reference to the info page at its end

Comment: @Ale - Yes, but the questioner hadn't seen it, as he said he could not find explanatory documentation, so I though it worth pointing out that it was there, in case he had further questions about other parameter sequences. He hasn't said which Unix he has, so he may need to load `info` as an optional package.

Comment: @AFH Good point, I upvoted your comment and extended my answer.

Comment: Yes it helped me in finding the solution. Thanks a lot to Werner and all.